# Error "None of... index are in the columns

Tags: python

I'm  trying to use the Stratified k-fold on my dataset but this is the error when i run the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

#leggo dataset
df_train = pd.read_csv("train_numeric_shuffled_50000_cleaned_90.csv")``
#creazione train set  
x_train=df_train.drop(['Id','Response'], axis=1)
y_train = df_train['Response']
#applico Stratified K-fold con 4 suddivisioni
skfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4)

for train_index, test_index in skfold.split(df_train, y_train):
    x_train_skf = df_train[train_index]
    x_test_skf = df_train[test_index]
    y_train_skf = y_train[train_index]
    y_test_skf = y_train[test_index]
```

This is the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12808\1982191024.py in <module>
1 # ciclo for per la creazione dei train e dei test
2 for train_index, test_index in skfold.split(df_train, y_train):
3     x_train_skf = df_train[train_index]
4     x_test_skf = df_train[test_index]
5     y_train_skf = y_train[train_index]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
3509             if is_iterator(key):
3510                 key = list(key)
3511             indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
3512 
3513         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)
5794             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
5795 
5796         self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
5797 
5798         keyarr = self.take(indexer)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
5854                 if use_interval_msg:
5855                     key = list(key)
5856                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
5857 
5858             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([11161, 11444, 11451, 11678, 12034, 12181, 12411, 12454, 12508, 12509,...49990, 49991, 49992, 49993, 49994, 49995, 49996, 49997, 49998,49999],dtype='int64', length=37500)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Please don't put code in quote blocks, instead put code in code blocks. The code will look better, and if you're using a language like python, indentation matters.

Comment: I don't fully understand what is in `train_index` and `test_index`, but could you try writing `df_train.loc[train_index, :]` and `df_train.loc[test_index, :]`, etc... to see if that resolve your issue?

Comment: @Yevhen Kuzmovych, why is it not appreciated to indicate the current research status of the OP?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke because you don't know the current research status of the OP. Don't write your assumptions into the edit (or any additional sentences). If you have a question or a comment, use comments. Thank you for the formatting fix though.

Comment: @MartinaPascucci, could you please let us know what you've looked into so far? It prevents that answerers suggest something that you've tried already and that didn't work.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Know I do not, strong suspicion I have...